# Hibernate 2nd level cache. Store immutable objects (intact) and other in hydraded form

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache, second-level-cache

Is it possible to turn on hibernate option `hibernate.cache.use_reference_entries` only for selected classes (in my case for immutable dictionaries)?

> hibernate.cache.use_reference_entries
>
> Optimizes second-level cache
> operation to store immutable entities (aka "reference") which do not
> have associations into cache directly, this case, lots of disasseble
> and deep copy operations can be avoid. Default value of this property
> is false.